# SpringMVC ActionMapping pass parameter from portlet:ActionURL

Tags: spring, jsp, model-view-controller, portlet

i'am trying to send parameter from my POST-Form on ActionMapping-Method.
My JSP-Code:

```
<portlet:actionURL name="answer" var="answerUrl">
    <portlet:param name="answerValue" value="${answerValue}"/>
    <portlet:param name="typus" value="${typus}"/>
</portlet:actionURL>

<form id="question" class="" action="${answerQuestionUrl}" method="POST">

<div class="dropdown">
    <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
        <option value=""></option>
        <c:forEach items="${dropDownMap}" var="entry">
            <option value="${entry.key}">${entry.value}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>       
<div class="clear">
    <div class="left"></div>
     <input type="image" name="submit" src="pic.png" class="operation-functions element-right" />
    <br class="clear">
</div>
```

And from this form i have to receive selected value from drop-box

```
@ActionMapping(value = "answer")
    public void answerQuestion(PortletRequest request, ActionResponse response, @RequestParam String answer, @RequestParam String typus){
    }
```

But both parameters "answer" and "typus" are empty.
How can i pass selected  valued from dropbox by ActionMapping and portlet:actionUrl.

Thx

Comment: I'm not too familiar with spring, but if i had to make an educated guess, I notice you're trying to access this dropdown's value of a form with a POST action with spring `RequestParam`, maybe it;s looking in `GET` params rather than the POST?

Comment: hhm...it should be post-request, but thx.